# Make cmake use its own build cache

Tags: makefile, cmake, gnu-make, gsutil

I'm building a CI/CD pipeline using Google Cloud Build (where the whole build process happens in a Docker container(s)). At some point I call `cmake` like this from `build` directory:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../ && \
cmake --build . --target all --config Release -- -j 25
```

The project structure (if simplified) looks like this then:

```
> build/
> src/
> CMakeLists.txt
```

The problem is that every time a new build starts the whole project is being recompiled no matter whether the sources were changed or not. To avoid this I save the whole `build` directory to Cloud Storage using `gsutil` and then in the beginning of each build using the same `gsutil` I retrieve the cache back to `build`. But when the `cmake` commands above start, the project is still getting recompiled completely.

As far as I know `cmake` (or underlying `make`) uses dumb "last modified" timestamps in order to determine whether to recompile anything or not. The thing is that `gsutil` completely erases these timestamps (and I won't use anything else than Cloud Storage).

So, the question is how do I make `cmake` treat the build cache properly?

Comment: This sort of defeats the whole point of CI, no?

Comment: @arrowd oh, please let's skip these "how do I do X?" - "You don't need to do X"

Comment: Sure. I'm just saying that anything highly unusual is often quite complex to implement/achieve.

Comment: @arrowd actually it's not the *true* CI/CD (you know, the one when you commit a change and it then gets deployed to prod) but rather a bunch of scripts to automate some things like: update version->lint->build->test->push version->push resultant image. And since the project is going to get big I really need to be able to build only last changes rather than rebuild everything. But I have an idea to check..

Comment: I assume after the sources are checked out, they'll have newer timestamps than the build files you saved.  No idea how to deal with this in a sane way though.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are asking how to have cmake treat the build cache "properly".  First, cmake itself doesn't do anything with deciding what to build.  Cmake is a tool that generates control files for various different build tools.  In your case you're using make so it's make that decides what to build.  As you know, make works 100% on timestamps.  If your underlying filesystem doesn't preserve timestamps when it copies files, then you simply cannot use it that way.

Comment: The only possible way to have this work is to preserve timestamps.  If your filesystem doesn't preserve per-file timestamps, one way to solve this is to not store individual files in the remote filesystem; instead, you can create a tar file or zip file that contains the files, both of which preserve timestamps, and store the tar/zip file in the remote filesystem.  Then retrieve the files by unpacking the tar/zip file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's about using `<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` to use ccache and copy the ccache cache instead of the build dir (IIRC ccache use hash instead of timestamp...) ?

ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/LANG_COMPILER_LAUNCHER.html

Comment: I already did that but with two little differences: 1) I save not the cache itself but a whole docker stage (I guess it's more reliable to do it this way), 2) I'm definitely against changing CMakeFiles in order for them to conform to different tools so I didn't use `<LANG>_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` but instead updated `PATH` so any call to `g++`/`gcc` is being redirected to `ccache`

Comment: I was thinking on using `-DCXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER=ccache` on the configure cmd line than hacking the CMakeLists.txt directly...